# Linq to SQL проблема с GetTable()

Tags: c#, база-данных, linq2sql

Можно ли выполнить запрос dataContext.GetTable(что-то но не класс)?
Зачем это нужно? Потому что я не могу создать определенный класс, потому что у меня будет меняться таблица во время работы программы.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113788/discussion-on-question-by-anton-kovalskyi-linq-to-sql---gettable).

Comment: Пингану дополнительно. Отредактируйте вопрос, перенесите из чата код: что вы хотите сделать.